# Clarifications regarding images that can/cannot be posted

Tags: discussion

Just wanted to clarify something regarding images that are used to support answers. I am referring, in particular, to this answer here: [What happens to Ichika after the fated summer ends?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21994/what-happens-to-ichika-after-the-fated-summer-ends/50318#50318)

While the answer is in English, the image used contains dialogues that are not in English and, moreover, seems to be from a scanlation group.

1. **Is including supporting images that are non-English to answers allowed?** I am asking since it might be hard to verify whether or not the answer is accurate if the source is not in English. I am not suggesting that non-English sources should not be allowed because some users translate their answers taken from non-English websites while including the original, and since other users can see the original source, they can further verify whether or not the translation is accurate.
2. **Is it alright to use images that are from scanlation groups?** I am not arguing on the legality since I think this was already addressed [here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4043/freely-accessible-manga-anime-e-g-webcomic-online-anime-and-scanlation-fansu) but rather on the accuracy of the translation from Japanese to whatever language it was translated to.

Comment: non-english pages are ok to so long as it's relevant but we'd rather if they were in english. personally i would like it if people explained what was going on in the page if it isn't english. ie *"above is from Chapter # Page # and character A says 'something something something' which roughly translates to this"*. scanlation images are fine from my understanding given that even an officially licensed translation can have the same degree of accuracy (to which some would argue fan translations are more accurate because some keep some japanese terms compared to the official translations)

Comment: I've added an English panel to the answer. I'm unsure of its official status but the translation seems solid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the rub with me is that the answer is relying on an unofficial source to make its point.

I would argue that the answer would be just as effective **if the image were not there**, so that'd be the path I'd want to pursue, if nothing else, to avoid a silly DMCA request when there really didn't need to be any.

To the main questions:

1. I would believe we would espouse **official English translations** if they are available.  If they are not, then freely and legally available Japanese source material (or limited scanned Japanese source material) may be acceptable.  In spite of the fact that we're talking about Manga and Anime, and some of us do consume it in Japanese, this is still an English-speaking site predominantly, and it is unreasonable to expect an answer to be in a different language than English.
2. **It depends.**  I lean towards "no" in general, but there may be [valid questions around the transliteration of a work](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/17032/102).  This sort of evaluation could be done on a case-by-case basis.